# Eigenvector of normalized graph Laplacian

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

I’m reading a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.08829) and they make a claim about the eigenvector of a graph Laplacian that seems wrong and I wanted to check with the larger community if I’m missing something obvious.

Let $G = (V,E,W)$ be a weighted undirected graph with $|V|=n$ and $W$ being the weighted adjacency matrix if $u$ is the vector of all ones then the degree vector is $(d_1, d_2, \dots, d_n)= d=Wu$. Denoting by $\sqrt{d}$ the element wise square root $\sqrt{d}=(\sqrt{d_1},\dots, \sqrt{d_n})$ then we can normalize the adjacency matrix to get $\tilde{W} = \operatorname{diag}(\sqrt{d})W\operatorname{diag}(\sqrt{d})$.

The claim is that the leading eigenvector associated to the largest eigenvalue is

$$v = \frac{\sqrt{d}}{\|\sqrt{d}\|_2} = \frac{d}{\|d\|_1}$$

My issue is the equality

$$\frac{\sqrt{d}}{\|\sqrt{d}\|_2} = \frac{d}{\|d\|_1}$$

This seems like it is obviously false. If we have the degree vector $d=(2,3,2,1)$ then $$\frac{\sqrt{d}}{\|\sqrt{d}\|_2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{7}}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{2},1)$$ and
$$\frac{d}{\|d\|_1} = \frac{1}{7}(2,3,2,1)$$
which are not equal after clearing radicals $\frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{7}}{7}\not=\frac{2}{7}$.

Is this an error by the authors or am I missing something?

Comment: Your correction has a minor error though it does not detract from your point: where you have 7 you should have 8. That being said, I am pretty sure they meant that one of them is the eigenvector after the transformation and the other is the eigenvector of the original matrix. They indeed can't just be the same, in fact they won't even be on the same line.